# How to import more-vert icon in material-ui for react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I tried a lot but i am not able to find a way to do it. Where is its exact location in material-ui? I saw some people using it. Any help is appreciated.

My best guess was :

```
import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/more-vert';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you install the icon library with `npm install -S @material-ui/icons` and then import it like this:

```
import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';
```

If you wonder what the name of a particular icon is, you can see them listed [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-icons/src).

Answer (score 2):

Mui `v5` import:

```
import MoreVertIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';
```

https://mui.com/components/material-icons/?query=MoreVert&selected=MoreVert

Answer (score 0):

Before use material ui icon You may need to import for that.
Steps:-

1. Open CMD
2. Copy this command:- " **npm install -S @material-ui/icons** "
3. Import icon that you want " **import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/more-vert';** "

Thanks